# Uniswap Emergency Withdraw - Masterchef Contract

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, uniswap, pancakeswap

I'm in search of where and how (if possible) I can do an emergency withdrawal on Uniswap V3.

In other pools I've seen, you can do so by finding the Masterchef contract ([pancake example](https://docs.pancakeswap.finance/developers/smart-contracts/main-staking-masterchef-contract)), entering the blockchain explorer i.e. polygonscan, ethscan, or bscscan and writing to the emergency withdraw function.

Can anyone tell me if:
Uniswap v3 has a masterchef contract, and if emergency withdraws are possible from their liquidity pool protocols?

Answer (score 1):

You can withdraw your liquidity from Uniswap v3 at any time. This includes times when it is an emergency or when it is not an emergency.

Uniswap offers multiple frontends, hosted or one that you can spin up from source code yourself. Also all smart contract are always accessible through various other methods, including Etherscan, Javascript, and so on.

Comment: My question is how to execute an withdrawal (remove liquidity of a pool) from Uniswap using  Etherscan and if there’s a mechanism like a masterchef contract to do so on uniswap like PancakeSwap allows when writing to its contract on BSCscan

Answer (score 0):

The emergency withdraw function on the MasterChef contract is for users to withdraw their funds (Withdraw without caring about rewards) from a liquidity pool even if the UI is down or the pool is under attack. This function is designed to protect users in the event of a rug pull or other malicious activity. This way user will get their funds faster.

I never seen such functionality in uniswap v3 neither on v4 docs. But you can use etherscan to call the functions.

[how-to-use-defi-without-a-frontend/](https://bowtiedisland.com/how-to-use-defi-without-a-frontend/)

> This set of instructions will be applicable, perhaps with some small
> modifications, to Uniswap V2, Sushiswap, Trader Joe, or any other
> Uniswap V2 fork DEX. If you need to swap via Uniswap V3 without a
> frontend, may God be with you.

Comment: Yep, V3 is the issue, no docs I could find on how to remove liquidity from a uniswap pool, not in their frontend site but rather on etherscan or elsewhere